# labelImg cannot run

Tags: python, labelimg

I installed labelImg on windows 10 with `pip install labelimg` and tried using the Create RectBox tool, which caused it to crash:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users...", line 530, in paintEvent
    p.drawLine(self.prev_point.x(), 0, self.prev_point.x(), self.pixmap.height())
TypeError: arguments did not match any overloaded call:
  drawLine(self, QLineF): argument 1 has unexpected type 'float'
  drawLine(self, QLine): argument 1 has unexpected type 'float'
  drawLine(self, int, int, int, int): argument 1 has unexpected type 'float'
  drawLine(self, QPoint, QPoint): argument 1 has unexpected type 'float'
  drawLine(self, Union[QPointF, QPoint], Union[QPointF, QPoint]): argument 1 has unexpected type 'float'
```

I have tired this with python 3.7 and 3.10 with the same result.

I have also tried downloading the code directly from https://github.com/tzutalin/labelImg, but there are all sorts of errors

```
> python labelImg.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users...\labelImg.py", line 29, in <module>
    from libs.resources import *
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'libs.resources'
```

(There is a `libs` folder, but no file named `resources` under it)

After commenting out this import line, I got an assertion error:

```
...... line 47, in get_string
    assert(string_id in self.id_to_message), "Missing string id : " + string_id
AssertionError: Missing string id : useDefaultLabel
```

Is there a version that works?

Comment: Here's an [alternative](https://github.com/unsignedrant/labelpix)

Answer (score 0):

Switch from lines 518 - 532 of canvas.py in libs of labelimg

From:

```
 if self.current is not None and len(self.line) == 2:
            left_top = self.line[0]
            right_bottom = self.line[1]
            rect_width = right_bottom.x() - left_top.x()
            rect_height = right_bottom.y() - left_top.y()
            p.setPen(self.drawing_rect_color)
            brush = QBrush(Qt.BDiagPattern)
            p.setBrush(brush)
            p.drawRect(int(left_top.x()), int(left_top.y()), rect_width, rect_height)
   


        if self.drawing() and not self.prev_point.isNull() and not self.out_of_pixmap(self.prev_point):
            p.setPen(QColor(0, 0, 0))
            p.drawLine(int(self.prev_point.x()), 0, int(self.prev_point.x()), self.pixmap.height())
            p.drawLine(0, int(self.prev_point.y()), self.pixmap.width(), int(self.prev_point.y()))
```

to:

```
if self.current is not None and len(self.line) == 2:
    left_top = self.line[0]
    right_bottom = self.line[1]
    rect_width = int(right_bottom.x() - left_top.x())  # Convert to integer
    rect_height = int(right_bottom.y() - left_top.y())  # Convert to integer
    p.setPen(self.drawing_rect_color)
    brush = QBrush(Qt.BDiagPattern)
    p.setBrush(brush)
    p.drawRect(int(left_top.x()), int(left_top.y()), rect_width, rect_height)
```

Answer (score -1):

I am a beginner coder.
I am gonna get straight to the point how to fix the bug above.
Simply get to the file of your path  "File "C:\Users...", line 530, in paintEvent...".
You will open file named "canvas.py". Replace all the codes in your recent file (I recommend you should have a copy of everything you change, just for back-up if everything is going too far) with the codes below:

***canvas.py***

```
try:
    from PyQt5.QtGui import *
    from PyQt5.QtCore import *
    from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
except ImportError:
    from PyQt4.QtGui import *
    from PyQt4.QtCore import *

# from PyQt4.QtOpenGL import *

from libs.shape import Shape
from libs.utils import distance

CURSOR_DEFAULT = Qt.ArrowCursor
CURSOR_POINT = Qt.PointingHandCursor
CURSOR_DRAW = Qt.CrossCursor
CURSOR_MOVE = Qt.ClosedHandCursor
CURSOR_GRAB = Qt.OpenHandCursor

# class Canvas(QGLWidget):


class Canvas(QWidget):
    zoomRequest = pyqtSignal(int)
    lightRequest = pyqtSignal(int)
    scrollRequest = pyqtSignal(int, int)
    newShape = pyqtSignal()
    selectionChanged = pyqtSignal(bool)
    shapeMoved = pyqtSignal()
    drawingPolygon = pyqtSignal(bool)

    CREATE, EDIT = list(range(2))

    epsilon = 24.0

def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(Canvas, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    # Initialise local state.
    self.mode = self.EDIT
    self.shapes = []
    self.current = None
    self.selected_shape = None  # save the selected shape here
    self.selected_shape_copy = None
    self.drawing_line_color = QColor(0, 0, 255)
    self.drawing_rect_color = QColor(0, 0, 255)
    self.line = Shape(line_color=self.drawing_line_color)
    self.prev_point = QPointF()
    self.offsets = QPointF(), QPointF()
    self.scale = 1.0
    self.overlay_color = None
    self.label_font_size = 8
    self.pixmap = QPixmap()
    self.visible = {}
    self._hide_background = False
    self.hide_background = False
    self.h_shape = None
    self.h_vertex = None
    self._painter = QPainter()
    self._cursor = CURSOR_DEFAULT
    # Menus:
    self.menus = (QMenu(), QMenu())
    # Set widget options.
    self.setMouseTracking(True)
    self.setFocusPolicy(Qt.WheelFocus)
    self.verified = False
    self.draw_square = False

    # initialisation for panning
    self.pan_initial_pos = QPoint()

def set_drawing_color(self, qcolor):
    self.drawing_line_color = qcolor
    self.drawing_rect_color = qcolor

def enterEvent(self, ev):
    self.override_cursor(self._cursor)

def leaveEvent(self, ev):
    self.restore_cursor()

def focusOutEvent(self, ev):
    self.restore_cursor()

def isVisible(self, shape):
    return self.visible.get(shape, True)

def drawing(self):
    return self.mode == self.CREATE

def editing(self):
    return self.mode == self.EDIT

def set_editing(self, value=True):
    self.mode = self.EDIT if value else self.CREATE
    if not value:  # Create
        self.un_highlight()
        self.de_select_shape()
    self.prev_point = QPointF()
    self.repaint()

def un_highlight(self, shape=None):
    if shape == None or shape == self.h_shape:
        if self.h_shape:
            self.h_shape.highlight_clear()
        self.h_vertex = self.h_shape = None

def selected_vertex(self):
    return self.h_vertex is not None

def mouseMoveEvent(self, ev):
    """Update line with last point and current coordinates."""
    pos = self.transform_pos(ev.pos())

    # Update coordinates in status bar if image is opened
    window = self.parent().window()
    if window.file_path is not None:
        self.parent().window().label_coordinates.setText(
            'X: %d; Y: %d' % (pos.x(), pos.y()))

    # Polygon drawing.
    if self.drawing():
        self.override_cursor(CURSOR_DRAW)
        if self.current:
            # Display annotation width and height while drawing
            current_width = abs(self.current[0].x() - pos.x())
            current_height = abs(self.current[0].y() - pos.y())
            self.parent().window().label_coordinates.setText(
                    'Width: %d, Height: %d / X: %d; Y: %d' % (current_width, current_height, pos.x(), pos.y()))

            color = self.drawing_line_color
            if self.out_of_pixmap(pos):
                # Don't allow the user to draw outside the pixmap.
                # Clip the coordinates to 0 or max,
                # if they are outside the range [0, max]
                size = self.pixmap.size()
                clipped_x = min(max(0, pos.x()), size.width())
                clipped_y = min(max(0, pos.y()), size.height())
                pos = QPointF(clipped_x, clipped_y)
            elif len(self.current) > 1 and self.close_enough(pos, self.current[0]):
                # Attract line to starting point and colorise to alert the
                # user:
                pos = self.current[0]
                color = self.current.line_color
                self.override_cursor(CURSOR_POINT)
                self.current.highlight_vertex(0, Shape.NEAR_VERTEX)

            if self.draw_square:
                init_pos = self.current[0]
                min_x = init_pos.x()
                min_y = init_pos.y()
                min_size = min(abs(pos.x() - min_x), abs(pos.y() - min_y))
                direction_x = -1 if pos.x() - min_x < 0 else 1
                direction_y = -1 if pos.y() - min_y < 0 else 1
                self.line[1] = QPointF(min_x + direction_x * min_size, min_y + direction_y * min_size)
            else:
                self.line[1] = pos

            self.line.line_color = color
            self.prev_point = QPointF()
            self.current.highlight_clear()
        else:
            self.prev_point = pos
        self.repaint()
        return

    # Polygon copy moving.
    if Qt.RightButton & ev.buttons():
        if self.selected_shape_copy and self.prev_point:
            self.override_cursor(CURSOR_MOVE)
            self.bounded_move_shape(self.selected_shape_copy, pos)
            self.repaint()
        elif self.selected_shape:
            self.selected_shape_copy = self.selected_shape.copy()
            self.repaint()
        return

    # Polygon/Vertex moving.
    if Qt.LeftButton & ev.buttons():
        if self.selected_vertex():
            self.bounded_move_vertex(pos)
            self.shapeMoved.emit()
            self.repaint()

            # Display annotation width and height while moving vertex
            point1 = self.h_shape[1]
            point3 = self.h_shape[3]
            current_width = abs(point1.x() - point3.x())
            current_height = abs(point1.y() - point3.y())
            self.parent().window().label_coordinates.setText(
                    'Width: %d, Height: %d / X: %d; Y: %d' % (current_width, current_height, pos.x(), pos.y()))
        elif self.selected_shape and self.prev_point:
            self.override_cursor(CURSOR_MOVE)
            self.bounded_move_shape(self.selected_shape, pos)
            self.shapeMoved.emit()
            self.repaint()

            # Display annotation width and height while moving shape
            point1 = self.selected_shape[1]
            point3 = self.selected_shape[3]
            current_width = abs(point1.x() - point3.x())
            current_height = abs(point1.y() - point3.y())
            self.parent().window().label_coordinates.setText(
                    'Width: %d, Height: %d / X: %d; Y: %d' % (current_width, current_height, pos.x(), pos.y()))
        else:
            # pan
            delta = ev.pos() - self.pan_initial_pos
            self.scrollRequest.emit(delta.x(), Qt.Horizontal)
            self.scrollRequest.emit(delta.y(), Qt.Vertical)
            self.update()
        return

    # Just hovering over the canvas, 2 possibilities:
    # - Highlight shapes
    # - Highlight vertex
    # Update shape/vertex fill and tooltip value accordingly.
    self.setToolTip("Image")
    priority_list = self.shapes + ([self.selected_shape] if self.selected_shape else [])
    for shape in reversed([s for s in priority_list if self.isVisible(s)]):
        # Look for a nearby vertex to highlight. If that fails,
        # check if we happen to be inside a shape.
        index = shape.nearest_vertex(pos, self.epsilon)
        if index is not None:
            if self.selected_vertex():
                self.h_shape.highlight_clear()
            self.h_vertex, self.h_shape = index, shape
            shape.highlight_vertex(index, shape.MOVE_VERTEX)
            self.override_cursor(CURSOR_POINT)
            self.setToolTip("Click & drag to move point")
            self.setStatusTip(self.toolTip())
            self.update()
            break
        elif shape.contains_point(pos):
            if self.selected_vertex():
                self.h_shape.highlight_clear()
            self.h_vertex, self.h_shape = None, shape
            self.setToolTip(
                "Click & drag to move shape '%s'" % shape.label)
            self.setStatusTip(self.toolTip())
            self.override_cursor(CURSOR_GRAB)
            self.update()

            # Display annotation width and height while hovering inside
            point1 = self.h_shape[1]
            point3 = self.h_shape[3]
            current_width = abs(point1.x() - point3.x())
            current_height = abs(point1.y() - point3.y())
            self.parent().window().label_coordinates.setText(
                    'Width: %d, Height: %d / X: %d; Y: %d' % (current_width, current_height, pos.x(), pos.y()))
            break
    else:  # Nothing found, clear highlights, reset state.
        if self.h_shape:
            self.h_shape.highlight_clear()
            self.update()
        self.h_vertex, self.h_shape = None, None
        self.override_cursor(CURSOR_DEFAULT)

def mousePressEvent(self, ev):
    pos = self.transform_pos(ev.pos())

    if ev.button() == Qt.LeftButton:
        if self.drawing():
            self.handle_drawing(pos)
        else:
            selection = self.select_shape_point(pos)
            self.prev_point = pos

            if selection is None:
                # pan
                QApplication.setOverrideCursor(QCursor(Qt.OpenHandCursor))
                self.pan_initial_pos = ev.pos()

    elif ev.button() == Qt.RightButton and self.editing():
        self.select_shape_point(pos)
        self.prev_point = pos
    self.update()

def mouseReleaseEvent(self, ev):
    if ev.button() == Qt.RightButton:
        menu = self.menus[bool(self.selected_shape_copy)]
        self.restore_cursor()
        if not menu.exec_(self.mapToGlobal(ev.pos()))\
           and self.selected_shape_copy:
            # Cancel the move by deleting the shadow copy.
            self.selected_shape_copy = None
            self.repaint()
    elif ev.button() == Qt.LeftButton and self.selected_shape:
        if self.selected_vertex():
            self.override_cursor(CURSOR_POINT)
        else:
            self.override_cursor(CURSOR_GRAB)
    elif ev.button() == Qt.LeftButton:
        pos = self.transform_pos(ev.pos())
        if self.drawing():
            self.handle_drawing(pos)
        else:
            # pan
            QApplication.restoreOverrideCursor()

def end_move(self, copy=False):
    assert self.selected_shape and self.selected_shape_copy
    shape = self.selected_shape_copy
    # del shape.fill_color
    # del shape.line_color
    if copy:
        self.shapes.append(shape)
        self.selected_shape.selected = False
        self.selected_shape = shape
        self.repaint()
    else:
        self.selected_shape.points = [p for p in shape.points]
    self.selected_shape_copy = None

def hide_background_shapes(self, value):
    self.hide_background = value
    if self.selected_shape:
        # Only hide other shapes if there is a current selection.
        # Otherwise the user will not be able to select a shape.
        self.set_hiding(True)
        self.repaint()

def handle_drawing(self, pos):
    if self.current and self.current.reach_max_points() is False:
        init_pos = self.current[0]
        min_x = init_pos.x()
        min_y = init_pos.y()
        target_pos = self.line[1]
        max_x = target_pos.x()
        max_y = target_pos.y()
        self.current.add_point(QPointF(max_x, min_y))
        self.current.add_point(target_pos)
        self.current.add_point(QPointF(min_x, max_y))
        self.finalise()
    elif not self.out_of_pixmap(pos):
        self.current = Shape()
        self.current.add_point(pos)
        self.line.points = [pos, pos]
        self.set_hiding()
        self.drawingPolygon.emit(True)
        self.update()

def set_hiding(self, enable=True):
    self._hide_background = self.hide_background if enable else False

def can_close_shape(self):
    return self.drawing() and self.current and len(self.current) > 2

def mouseDoubleClickEvent(self, ev):
    # We need at least 4 points here, since the mousePress handler
    # adds an extra one before this handler is called.
    if self.can_close_shape() and len(self.current) > 3:
        self.current.pop_point()
        self.finalise()

def select_shape(self, shape):
    self.de_select_shape()
    shape.selected = True
    self.selected_shape = shape
    self.set_hiding()
    self.selectionChanged.emit(True)
    self.update()

def select_shape_point(self, point):
    """Select the first shape created which contains this point."""
    self.de_select_shape()
    if self.selected_vertex():  # A vertex is marked for selection.
        index, shape = self.h_vertex, self.h_shape
        shape.highlight_vertex(index, shape.MOVE_VERTEX)
        self.select_shape(shape)
        return self.h_vertex
    for shape in reversed(self.shapes):
        if self.isVisible(shape) and shape.contains_point(point):
            self.select_shape(shape)
            self.calculate_offsets(shape, point)
            return self.selected_shape
    return None

def calculate_offsets(self, shape, point):
    rect = shape.bounding_rect()
    x1 = rect.x() - point.x()
    y1 = rect.y() - point.y()
    x2 = (rect.x() + rect.width()) - point.x()
    y2 = (rect.y() + rect.height()) - point.y()
    self.offsets = QPointF(x1, y1), QPointF(x2, y2)

def snap_point_to_canvas(self, x, y):
    """
    Moves a point x,y to within the boundaries of the canvas.
    :return: (x,y,snapped) where snapped is True if x or y were changed, False if not.
    """
    if x < 0 or x > self.pixmap.width() or y < 0 or y > self.pixmap.height():
        x = max(x, 0)
        y = max(y, 0)
        x = min(x, self.pixmap.width())
        y = min(y, self.pixmap.height())
        return x, y, True

    return x, y, False

def bounded_move_vertex(self, pos):
    index, shape = self.h_vertex, self.h_shape
    point = shape[index]
    if self.out_of_pixmap(pos):
        size = self.pixmap.size()
        clipped_x = min(max(0, pos.x()), size.width())
        clipped_y = min(max(0, pos.y()), size.height())
        pos = QPointF(clipped_x, clipped_y)

    if self.draw_square:
        opposite_point_index = (index + 2) % 4
        opposite_point = shape[opposite_point_index]

        min_size = min(abs(pos.x() - opposite_point.x()), abs(pos.y() - opposite_point.y()))
        direction_x = -1 if pos.x() - opposite_point.x() < 0 else 1
        direction_y = -1 if pos.y() - opposite_point.y() < 0 else 1
        shift_pos = QPointF(opposite_point.x() + direction_x * min_size - point.x(),
                            opposite_point.y() + direction_y * min_size - point.y())
    else:
        shift_pos = pos - point

    shape.move_vertex_by(index, shift_pos)

    left_index = (index + 1) % 4
    right_index = (index + 3) % 4
    left_shift = None
    right_shift = None
    if index % 2 == 0:
        right_shift = QPointF(shift_pos.x(), 0)
        left_shift = QPointF(0, shift_pos.y())
    else:
        left_shift = QPointF(shift_pos.x(), 0)
        right_shift = QPointF(0, shift_pos.y())
    shape.move_vertex_by(right_index, right_shift)
    shape.move_vertex_by(left_index, left_shift)

def bounded_move_shape(self, shape, pos):
    if self.out_of_pixmap(pos):
        return False  # No need to move
    o1 = pos + self.offsets[0]
    if self.out_of_pixmap(o1):
        pos -= QPointF(min(0, o1.x()), min(0, o1.y()))
    o2 = pos + self.offsets[1]
    if self.out_of_pixmap(o2):
        pos += QPointF(min(0, self.pixmap.width() - o2.x()),
                       min(0, self.pixmap.height() - o2.y()))
    # The next line tracks the new position of the cursor
    # relative to the shape, but also results in making it
    # a bit "shaky" when nearing the border and allows it to
    # go outside of the shape's area for some reason. XXX
    # self.calculateOffsets(self.selectedShape, pos)
    dp = pos - self.prev_point
    if dp:
        shape.move_by(dp)
        self.prev_point = pos
        return True
    return False

def de_select_shape(self):
    if self.selected_shape:
        self.selected_shape.selected = False
        self.selected_shape = None
        self.set_hiding(False)
        self.selectionChanged.emit(False)
        self.update()

def delete_selected(self):
    if self.selected_shape:
        shape = self.selected_shape
        self.un_highlight(shape)
        self.shapes.remove(self.selected_shape)
        self.selected_shape = None
        self.update()
        return shape

def copy_selected_shape(self):
    if self.selected_shape:
        shape = self.selected_shape.copy()
        self.de_select_shape()
        self.shapes.append(shape)
        shape.selected = True
        self.selected_shape = shape
        self.bounded_shift_shape(shape)
        return shape

def bounded_shift_shape(self, shape):
    # Try to move in one direction, and if it fails in another.
    # Give up if both fail.
    point = shape[0]
    offset = QPointF(2.0, 2.0)
    self.calculate_offsets(shape, point)
    self.prev_point = point
    if not self.bounded_move_shape(shape, point - offset):
        self.bounded_move_shape(shape, point + offset)

def paintEvent(self, event):
    if not self.pixmap:
        return super(Canvas, self).paintEvent(event)

    p = self._painter
    p.begin(self)
    p.setRenderHint(QPainter.Antialiasing)
    p.setRenderHint(QPainter.HighQualityAntialiasing)
    p.setRenderHint(QPainter.SmoothPixmapTransform)

    p.scale(self.scale, self.scale)
    p.translate(self.offset_to_center())

    temp = self.pixmap
    if self.overlay_color:
        temp = QPixmap(self.pixmap)
        painter = QPainter(temp)
        painter.setCompositionMode(painter.CompositionMode_Overlay)
        painter.fillRect(temp.rect(), self.overlay_color)
        painter.end()

    p.drawPixmap(0, 0, temp)
    Shape.scale = self.scale
    Shape.label_font_size = self.label_font_size
    for shape in self.shapes:
        if (shape.selected or not self._hide_background) and self.isVisible(shape):
            shape.fill = shape.selected or shape == self.h_shape
            shape.paint(p)
    if self.current:
        self.current.paint(p)
        self.line.paint(p)
    if self.selected_shape_copy:
        self.selected_shape_copy.paint(p)

    # Paint rect
    if self.current is not None and len(self.line) == 2:
        left_top = self.line[0]
        right_bottom = self.line[1]
        rect_width = right_bottom.x() - left_top.x()
        rect_height = right_bottom.y() - left_top.y()
        p.setPen(self.drawing_rect_color)
        brush = QBrush(Qt.BDiagPattern)
        p.setBrush(brush)
        p.drawRect(int(left_top.x()), int(left_top.y()), int(rect_width), int(rect_height))

    if self.drawing() and not self.prev_point.isNull() and not self.out_of_pixmap(self.prev_point):
        p.setPen(QColor(0, 0, 0))
        p.drawLine(int(self.prev_point.x()), 0, int(self.prev_point.x()), int(self.pixmap.height()))
        p.drawLine(0, int(self.prev_point.y()), int(self.pixmap.width()), int(self.prev_point.y()))

    self.setAutoFillBackground(True)
    if self.verified:
        pal = self.palette()
        pal.setColor(self.backgroundRole(), QColor(184, 239, 38, 128))
        self.setPalette(pal)
    else:
        pal = self.palette()
        pal.setColor(self.backgroundRole(), QColor(232, 232, 232, 255))
        self.setPalette(pal)

    p.end()

def transform_pos(self, point):
    """Convert from widget-logical coordinates to painter-logical coordinates."""
    return point / self.scale - self.offset_to_center()

def offset_to_center(self):
    s = self.scale
    area = super(Canvas, self).size()
    w, h = self.pixmap.width() * s, self.pixmap.height() * s
    aw, ah = area.width(), area.height()
    x = (aw - w) / (2 * s) if aw > w else 0
    y = (ah - h) / (2 * s) if ah > h else 0
    return QPointF(x, y)

def out_of_pixmap(self, p):
    w, h = self.pixmap.width(), self.pixmap.height()
    return not (0 <= p.x() <= w and 0 <= p.y() <= h)

def finalise(self):
    assert self.current
    if self.current.points[0] == self.current.points[-1]:
        self.current = None
        self.drawingPolygon.emit(False)
        self.update()
        return

    self.current.close()
    self.shapes.append(self.current)
    self.current = None
    self.set_hiding(False)
    self.newShape.emit()
    self.update()

def close_enough(self, p1, p2):
    # d = distance(p1 - p2)
    # m = (p1-p2).manhattanLength()
    # print "d %.2f, m %d, %.2f" % (d, m, d - m)
    return distance(p1 - p2) < self.epsilon

# These two, along with a call to adjustSize are required for the
# scroll area.
def sizeHint(self):
    return self.minimumSizeHint()

def minimumSizeHint(self):
    if self.pixmap:
        return self.scale * self.pixmap.size()
    return super(Canvas, self).minimumSizeHint()

def wheelEvent(self, ev):
    qt_version = 4 if hasattr(ev, "delta") else 5
    if qt_version == 4:
        if ev.orientation() == Qt.Vertical:
            v_delta = ev.delta()
            h_delta = 0
        else:
            h_delta = ev.delta()
            v_delta = 0
    else:
        delta = ev.angleDelta()
        h_delta = delta.x()
        v_delta = delta.y()

    mods = ev.modifiers()
    if int(Qt.ControlModifier) | int(Qt.ShiftModifier) == int(mods) and v_delta:
        self.lightRequest.emit(v_delta)
    elif Qt.ControlModifier == int(mods) and v_delta:
        self.zoomRequest.emit(v_delta)
    else:
        v_delta and self.scrollRequest.emit(v_delta, Qt.Vertical)
        h_delta and self.scrollRequest.emit(h_delta, Qt.Horizontal)
    ev.accept()

def keyPressEvent(self, ev):
    key = ev.key()
    if key == Qt.Key_Escape and self.current:
        print('ESC press')
        self.current = None
        self.drawingPolygon.emit(False)
        self.update()
    elif key == Qt.Key_Return and self.can_close_shape():
        self.finalise()
    elif key == Qt.Key_Left and self.selected_shape:
        self.move_one_pixel('Left')
    elif key == Qt.Key_Right and self.selected_shape:
        self.move_one_pixel('Right')
    elif key == Qt.Key_Up and self.selected_shape:
        self.move_one_pixel('Up')
    elif key == Qt.Key_Down and self.selected_shape:
        self.move_one_pixel('Down')

def move_one_pixel(self, direction):
    # print(self.selectedShape.points)
    if direction == 'Left' and not self.move_out_of_bound(QPointF(-1.0, 0)):
        # print("move Left one pixel")
        self.selected_shape.points[0] += QPointF(-1.0, 0)
        self.selected_shape.points[1] += QPointF(-1.0, 0)
        self.selected_shape.points[2] += QPointF(-1.0, 0)
        self.selected_shape.points[3] += QPointF(-1.0, 0)
    elif direction == 'Right' and not self.move_out_of_bound(QPointF(1.0, 0)):
        # print("move Right one pixel")
        self.selected_shape.points[0] += QPointF(1.0, 0)
        self.selected_shape.points[1] += QPointF(1.0, 0)
        self.selected_shape.points[2] += QPointF(1.0, 0)
        self.selected_shape.points[3] += QPointF(1.0, 0)
    elif direction == 'Up' and not self.move_out_of_bound(QPointF(0, -1.0)):
        # print("move Up one pixel")
        self.selected_shape.points[0] += QPointF(0, -1.0)
        self.selected_shape.points[1] += QPointF(0, -1.0)
        self.selected_shape.points[2] += QPointF(0, -1.0)
        self.selected_shape.points[3] += QPointF(0, -1.0)
    elif direction == 'Down' and not self.move_out_of_bound(QPointF(0, 1.0)):
        # print("move Down one pixel")
        self.selected_shape.points[0] += QPointF(0, 1.0)
        self.selected_shape.points[1] += QPointF(0, 1.0)
        self.selected_shape.points[2] += QPointF(0, 1.0)
        self.selected_shape.points[3] += QPointF(0, 1.0)
    self.shapeMoved.emit()
    self.repaint()

def move_out_of_bound(self, step):
    points = [p1 + p2 for p1, p2 in zip(self.selected_shape.points, [step] * 4)]
    return True in map(self.out_of_pixmap, points)

def set_last_label(self, text, line_color=None, fill_color=None):
    assert text
    self.shapes[-1].label = text
    if line_color:
        self.shapes[-1].line_color = line_color

    if fill_color:
        self.shapes[-1].fill_color = fill_color

    return self.shapes[-1]

def undo_last_line(self):
    assert self.shapes
    self.current = self.shapes.pop()
    self.current.set_open()
    self.line.points = [self.current[-1], self.current[0]]
    self.drawingPolygon.emit(True)

def reset_all_lines(self):
    assert self.shapes
    self.current = self.shapes.pop()
    self.current.set_open()
    self.line.points = [self.current[-1], self.current[0]]
    self.drawingPolygon.emit(True)
    self.current = None
    self.drawingPolygon.emit(False)
    self.update()

def load_pixmap(self, pixmap):
    self.pixmap = pixmap
    self.shapes = []
    self.repaint()

def load_shapes(self, shapes):
    self.shapes = list(shapes)
    self.current = None
    self.repaint()

def set_shape_visible(self, shape, value):
    self.visible[shape] = value
    self.repaint()

def current_cursor(self):
    cursor = QApplication.overrideCursor()
    if cursor is not None:
        cursor = cursor.shape()
    return cursor

def override_cursor(self, cursor):
    self._cursor = cursor
    if self.current_cursor() is None:
        QApplication.setOverrideCursor(cursor)
    else:
        QApplication.changeOverrideCursor(cursor)

def restore_cursor(self):
    QApplication.restoreOverrideCursor()

def reset_state(self):
    self.de_select_shape()
    self.un_highlight()
    self.selected_shape_copy = None

    self.restore_cursor()
    self.pixmap = None
    self.update()

def set_drawing_shape_to_square(self, status):
    self.draw_square = status
```

**End of code**

Hope it help!